# Isolating a variable x in an equation with a variable y, to the third power

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations

I have an equation:

$x^3 - 4x^2 + 10x - y^3 +4y^2 - 10 y = 0$

I need to isolate x or y.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: And that seems to be two questions? The one involving the partial derivatives. It seems to be unrelated to the first question.

Comment: The first equation does not imply that $x=y$. What is true is that every pair $(x,y)=(t,t)$ does satisfy the equation, but other pairs may too.

Comment: I made my question more concise. I hope this helps you understand my problem better.

Comment: Try to use $x^3 - y^3 = (x-y)(x^2 + xy+y^2)$ and similar for $x^2 -y^2$. That would pull out a $x-y$ and the remaining term is quadratic.

Comment: I haven't set one yet. I made this account about 20  minutes ago.

Comment: I succeeded in isolating x with your suggestion, Artic Char. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the derivative of $f(x)= x^3-4x^2+10x$ is $f'(x) = 3x^2-8x+10>0$ for all $x$ so $f$ is strictly increasing and thus injective.

Since your equation is actually $f(x)=f(y)$ we deduce $x=y$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This helps confirm my doubts.